# How does data structure in Firestore affect optimization, speed, and cost of queries in large datasets?

Tags: firebase, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

With the data structure here

```
+Nike
  --Day1
      timestamp: 11-11-2020
            +Mentions
                    --001
                         timestamp: 11-11-2020
                    --002
                         timestamp: 11-11-2020
  --Day2
      timestamp: 11-12-2020
            +Mentions
                    --001
                         timestamp: 11-12-2020
                    --002
                         timestamp: 11-12-2020
```

if I ditch the hierarchy and just dump all the mentions into one collection and don't break them out by date, is that querying expensive because it has to search every mentions timestamp as well?

```
+Nike
          --001
                   timestamp: 11-11-2020
           --002
                  timestamp: 11-11-2020
           --003
                   timestamp: 11-12-2020
           --004
                  timestamp: 11-12-2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuitive wish to query less data, is actually not needed when using Firestore. **Firestore query performance does not depend on the amount of data you query, but only on the amount of data you retrieve.** So duplicating the day into each mention is the right approach here, and quite common.

I'd recommend to still keep the mentions per day, but for a different reason: **write** performance. On Firestore you're mostly affected by limits on write performance, specifically the indexes that Firestore needs to update. By segmenting the mentions across multiple subcollections you'll reduce the number of joint indexes that Firestore needs to update, although the need for a collection group query *does* mean that you have at least one index across all mentions that needs updating.

Comment: 2) There no real difference in the resulting index in that case, but you still have better *data* locality. This typically helps for general write throughput, although that is probably not a factor given the values you provided.